# My wordpress website is not working after I change the AWS instance type?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2

I changed the instance type of my ubuntu AWS instance. After changing this, WordPress website is not listening to the new public IP.
I have access of the instance and the website folder is also there in /var/www/html/wordpress/

When I open the IP address the apache2 welcome page is opening not the WordPress website.
When I try to access the website in a browser like this newip/wordpress/ then it redirects to the old IP address (oldip/wordpress) and in the browser it is showing that the site is not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the instance type, you must first stop the instance. When you stop an instance, AWS release the public IPv4 address and give your instance a new public IPv4 address.

Comment: I did the same way. First I stop the instance and then change the instance from the action menu option.